What are some alternatives to bevel gears for 90 degree motion change?
I'm a robotics hobbyist, with fairly limited budget and manufacturing capabilities. I have a 3d printer, and access to CNC sheet metal cutting.
I'm working on a space constrained robot drivetrain, which I need to transfer rotational motion around a corner for. Unfortunately I'm struggling to find suitably compact bevel gears, and I would rather not 3D print them. Are there any compact alternatives for transferring motion around 90 degree corners that fall within my manufacturing capabilities?
I've thought about twisted belts, but it seems like this would cause the belts to degrade according to this answer. I was also looking at Syncromesh cable, but it appears to lack sufficient precision according to this question.

can you give an idea of the space you allocated for this, and what kind of torque you expect to need to transfer? 3D printing will probably be fine TBH

O rings instead of belts?

And what is "limited budget" ? That could be hundreds or thousands...

You might consider speedometer cable or tachometer cable which is made up of many small diameter wires for flexibility and have long life at moderate rpm and torque levels.
